# Is there a piece of equipment that connects to a wireless network and provides ethernet ports to clients?

Tags: networking, wifi, switch

Is there a piece of equipment that connects to a wireless network and provides ethernet ports to clients?

I have an existing wireless network, and I would like to plug a bunch of machines into a single switch that uses the wireless network as an uplink.

Is this possible, or is this a bad idea? The bandwidth utilization through this link should be negligible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a wireless ethernet bridge. One example is http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/products/WET610N

Comment: Thanks! "Wireless ethernet bridge" was the term I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with commodity wireless router, set in a bridged mode. If the build-in firmware does not support this, you can try some of the opensource firmwares like [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/), [openwrt](http://openwrt.org/), [tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato), etc. Check the hardware support list for these.